# Div isn't at cursor position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a custom range slider. I'm having trouble getting the cursors position in percentage (i.e. 1 - 100).

Here's the relevant code:

```
var cursorPosition = 1 - clamp((sliderDimention - (e.clientX - startPoint.left)) / sliderDimention, 0, 1);
sliderRange.style.transform = 'scaleX' + '(' + (cursorPosition * sliderDimention - cursorRadius) + ')';

function clamp(value, min, max) {
    return Math.min(Math.max(value, min), max);
}
```

I have a sliderCursor and a sliderRange (the green background). I was able to implement the sliderCursor, but I'm having trouble with the sliderRange. It's not exactly where the cursor is.

How can I get the sliderRange to be at the exact position of the cursor? Also, the sliderRange goes past the sliders border. How can I prevent that?

(Please don't post any JQuery or other "you can use 'this' plugin" answers. I'm doing this for learning purposes, and I want to create my own. Thanks!)

#### JSFiddile

```js
function RangeSlider( /** DOM Elem */ parentElem) {
  var wrapperElem = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapperElem')[0],
    slider = document.getElementsByClassName('slider')[0],
    sliderCursor = document.getElementsByClassName('sliderCursor')[0],
    sliderRange = document.getElementsByClassName('sliderRange')[0];

  var sliderDimention = slider.offsetWidth,
    cursorRadius = sliderCursor.offsetHeight / 2,
    startPoint,
    currentTarget;


  function sliderDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    currentTarget = null;
    var sliderWithDescendents = wrapperElem.querySelectorAll('*');
    for (var i = 0; i < sliderWithDescendents.length; i++) {
      sliderWithDescendents[i]
      if (sliderWithDescendents[i] === e.target || wrapperElem === e.target) {
        currentTarget = wrapperElem.children[0];
        break;
      }
    }
    if (currentTarget === null) return;

    startPoint = getOrigin(currentTarget);
    sliderDimention = slider.offsetWidth;

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', sliderMove);
    sliderMove(e);
  }

  function sliderMove(e) {
    var cursorPosition = e.clientX - startPoint.left - cursorRadius;
    cursorPosition = clamp(cursorPosition, startPoint.left - cursorRadius + 1, sliderDimention - 1 - cursorRadius * 2);
    sliderCursor.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (cursorPosition) + 'px)';
    cursorPosition = 1 - clamp((sliderDimention - (e.clientX - startPoint.left)) / sliderDimention, 0, 1);
    sliderRange.style.transform = 'scaleX' + '(' + (cursorPosition * sliderDimention - cursorRadius) + ')';
  }

  function mouseUpEvents() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', sliderMove);
  }
  wrapperElem.addEventListener('mousedown', sliderDown);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpEvents);
}

var sliderTest = document.getElementById('sliderTest');
var test = new RangeSlider(sliderTest);






function clamp(value, min, max) {
  return Math.min(Math.max(value, min), max);
}


function getOrigin(elm) {
  var box = (elm.getBoundingClientRect) ? elm.getBoundingClientRect() : {
      top: 0,
      left: 0
    },
    doc = elm && elm.ownerDocument,
    body = doc.body,
    win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow || window,
    docElem = doc.documentElement || body.parentNode,
    clientTop = docElem.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0, // border on html or body or both
    clientLeft = docElem.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0;

  return {
    left: box.left + (win.pageXOffset || docElem.scrollLeft) - clientLeft,
    top: box.top + (win.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop) - clientTop
  };
}
```

```css
.wrapperElem {
  height: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
}
.slider {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
.sliderCursor {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.sliderRange {
  background-color: green;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: left;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapperElem">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="sliderRange"></div>
    <div class="sliderCursor"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: they are in the same positions for me. If I click and drag the circle, it moves with the mouse... can you clarify a bit?

Comment: @Adjit Yes, you're correct. But the slider isn't at the center of the mouses cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your issue is, is that you are subtracting `cursorRadius` out of the `scaleX` function, meanwhile, you have already accounted for the cursors radius in your `cursorPosition`.

Try:

```
sliderRange.style.transform = 'scaleX' + '(' + (cursorPosition * sliderDimention) + ')';
```

```js
function RangeSlider( /** DOM Elem */ parentElem) {
  var wrapperElem = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapperElem')[0],
    slider = document.getElementsByClassName('slider')[0],
    sliderCursor = document.getElementsByClassName('sliderCursor')[0],
    sliderRange = document.getElementsByClassName('sliderRange')[0];

  var sliderDimention = slider.offsetWidth,
    cursorRadius = sliderCursor.offsetHeight / 2,
    startPoint,
    currentTarget;


  function sliderDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    currentTarget = null;
    var sliderWithDescendents = wrapperElem.querySelectorAll('*');
    for (var i = 0; i < sliderWithDescendents.length; i++) {
      sliderWithDescendents[i]
      if (sliderWithDescendents[i] === e.target || wrapperElem === e.target) {
        currentTarget = wrapperElem.children[0];
        break;
      }
    }
    if (currentTarget === null) return;

    startPoint = getOrigin(currentTarget);
    sliderDimention = slider.offsetWidth;

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', sliderMove);
    sliderMove(e);
  }

  function sliderMove(e) {
    var cursorPosition = e.clientX - startPoint.left - cursorRadius;
    cursorPosition = clamp(cursorPosition, startPoint.left - cursorRadius + 1, sliderDimention - 1 - cursorRadius * 2);
    sliderCursor.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (cursorPosition) + 'px)';
    cursorPosition = 1 - clamp((sliderDimention - (e.clientX - startPoint.left)) / sliderDimention, 0, 1);
    sliderRange.style.transform = 'scaleX' + '(' + (cursorPosition * sliderDimention) + ')';
  }

  function mouseUpEvents() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', sliderMove);
  }
  wrapperElem.addEventListener('mousedown', sliderDown);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpEvents);
}

var sliderTest = document.getElementById('sliderTest');
var test = new RangeSlider(sliderTest);






function clamp(value, min, max) {
  return Math.min(Math.max(value, min), max);
}


function getOrigin(elm) {
  var box = (elm.getBoundingClientRect) ? elm.getBoundingClientRect() : {
      top: 0,
      left: 0
    },
    doc = elm && elm.ownerDocument,
    body = doc.body,
    win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow || window,
    docElem = doc.documentElement || body.parentNode,
    clientTop = docElem.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0, // border on html or body or both
    clientLeft = docElem.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0;

  return {
    left: box.left + (win.pageXOffset || docElem.scrollLeft) - clientLeft,
    top: box.top + (win.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop) - clientTop
  };
}
```

```css
.wrapperElem {
  height: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
}
.slider {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
.sliderCursor {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.sliderRange {
  background-color: green;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: left;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapperElem">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="sliderRange"></div>
    <div class="sliderCursor"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! With your logic, I tried adding the code similar to the sliderCursors like this: `cursorPosition = e.clientX - startPoint.left;
    cursorPosition = clamp(cursorPosition, startPoint.left, sliderDimention);` but the sliderRange doesn't drag to the begining of the slider: https://jsfiddle.net/us6gr4v7/

Comment: Why are you changing the slideCursor? it works in my snippet. It will go to the end, but the cursor doesn't go outside of the slider

Comment: You're right, that your code works, but is there a way to do it with the code I posted in the comment above?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you should not update the DOM from the sliderMove function. In my opinion you should have a "private" variable _percent in your object (that you could initialize when you create the instance of your object for example). In the sliderMove you should only update the _percent variable regarding several things : the offset, the size of your slide element etc... The aim is to calculate the new percentage.

Then at the end of the sliderMove function you just call refreshDOM which will be in charge for refreshing the view as well. Doing it this way, you will be able to prevent the cursor to move in the sliderMove function (if _prevent == 0 and the offset is negative or if _prevent == 100 and the offset is positive for example...)

For your problem of the cursor position, I don't know... I don't reproduce and your code seems to be ok...

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand exactly how to implement what you said to do, but, before we get to that, lemme try to understand what I'm gaining by this. The difference between what I did, and what you suggest, is, I should remove the clamp function, and instead have a variable _prevent?